# Python - pandas - Time series data with picosecond precision

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use Pandas as I am working with Simulation data with picosecond precision. Since the dataset is not equidistantly sampled I want to use the resampling functionality provided in Pandas.

As far as I see, I need the time as datetime datatype. The numpy datetime64 datatype seems to support picosecond resolution, but Panda uses ns resolution.

Is there a way to overcome this problem? Or can I use a column of a non datetime like type (e.g. normal float) as index for `pandas.DataFrame.resample`?

Comment: Any update on that in pandas 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

Pitifully pandas does not support `picoseconds` you can read more information regarding the issue [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.replace.html) in pandas' documentation.

```
year : int, optional
month : int, optional
day : int, optional
hour : int, optional
minute : int, optional
second : int, optional
microsecond : int, optional
nanosecond : int, optional
```

Furthermore, you could add an extra column with an `integer` that would represent the picosecond value, and then concatenate it to the datetime object, into a full string that reach picosecond precision. Further more if you use `yyyymmddhhmmssmsusnsps` format you shouldn't have any issue with the sorting.

An extra column the precision of your resampling and a groupby to wrap it up.